# Create a Map from the elements of the same set based on condition in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, set, scala-collections

I have a `Hashset` of the following form, it might grow big:

```
var hs = HashSet(("fox", "name"),
    ("animal", "type"),
    ("gender", "type"),
    ("x", "test"),
    ("x", "nottest"),
    ("z", "test"),
    ("z", "nottest"))
```

What is the best way to have a Map from it with the following form:

```
HashMap (("x", "test")-> ("x", "nottest"),("z", "test") ->("z", "nottest"))
```

i.e Mapping the tuples from the same set where they have the same first element and the second element is prefixed with "not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create all possible pairs and filter out the ones, that are not present in the original set:

```
hs.map { case(k, v) => (k, v) -> (k, "not" + v) }
  .filter { case(pos, neg) => hs.contains(neg) }
  .toMap
```

Edit:

If the set grows really large, then we can easily change the ordering - first check and filter only pairs with negations, then map:

```
hs.filter { case(k, v) => hs((k, "not" + v)) }
  .map { case(k, v) => (k, v) -> (k, "not" + v) }
  .toMap
```

Comment: The set might go large, is there a way not to create all pairs? Plus, a tuple might exists but its negated one might or vise versa (I should have mentioned this in the question, will edit it)

Comment: @Usr654789 easy, we can change the ordering of operations, check out my edit;>

Comment: @Usr654789 did you run it? It yields the exact result you want. It doesn't matter whether for `(sth, notsth)` `(sth, sth)` exists. Checking one way is sufficient...

Comment: Just did yes, the result is filtered correctly but still a HashSet not a HashMap : HashSet(((z,test),(z,nottest)), ((x,test),(x,nottest)))

Comment: @Usr654789 ah, forgot about it, just call `toMap` on it...